pandas.DataFrame.apply with row names and coulmn names as arguments
Is there a way to use the apply function and pass the name of the specific row and column of each cell as arguments? In other words, I want to perform an operation to the cartesian product of two sets. Example:
countries = ["Germany", "France", "Belgium"]
years = [2030, 2040, 2050]
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = countries, index = years)

def myFunc(countryname, year):
   return countryname + str(year)

df.apply(myFunc) # I don't know how to pass the arguments

Maybe there is another way to do this without using nested for-loops?

No, there isn't, map which is the element-wise apply only gets the value.
You could however use a python loop and the DataFrame constructor:
out = pd.DataFrame(
    [[myFunc(c, y) for c in df.columns] for y in df.index],
    index=df.index,
    columns=df.columns,
)

Output:
          Germany      France      Belgium
2030  Germany2030  France2030  Belgium2030
2040  Germany2040  France2040  Belgium2040
2050  Germany2050  France2050  Belgium2050

Note that if your operation can be vectorized, you should use numpy broadcasting instead of a nested loop:
df.columns.to_numpy() + df.index.astype(str).to_numpy()[:, None]

array([['Germany2030', 'France2030', 'Belgium2030'],
       ['Germany2040', 'France2040', 'Belgium2040'],
       ['Germany2050', 'France2050', 'Belgium2050']], dtype=object)

If, not, you can vectorize it:
from numpy import vectorize

@vectorize
def myFunc(countryname, year):
   return countryname + str(year)

arr = myFunc(df.columns.to_numpy(), df.index.to_numpy()[:, None])

out = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)


Is the python loop faster/better than two ordinary for loops or is it just another way of writing it?

@tintinnabulum I think it's a tiny bit faster, but otherwise as "slow" as python loops can be (compared to potentially vectorized operations if your data is numeric).

One option is to use pd.MultiIndex.from_product()
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([countries,years]).to_series().map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format).unstack(level=0)

Output:
          Belgium      France      Germany
2030  Belgium2030  France2030  Germany2030
2040  Belgium2040  France2040  Germany2040
2050  Belgium2050  France2050  Germany2050


Another possible solution, which takes the following steps:

product(df.columns, df.index) creates a Cartesian product of the column names and row indices of the dataframe.

[myFunc(x, y) for x, y in product(df.columns, df.index)] applies myFunc to each combination of column and row index, resulting in a list of function outputs.

np.reshape(..., (len(df), -1)) reshapes this list into a 2D numpy array with len(df) rows and as many columns as needed.

pd.DataFrame(..., columns=df.columns, index=df.index) converts the reshaped array into a dataframe with the same column names and row indices as df.


from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame(
    np.reshape(
        [myFunc(x, y) for x, y in product(df.columns, df.index)], (len(df),-1)), 
    columns = df.columns, index = df.index)

Output:
          Germany       France      Belgium
2030  Germany2030  Germany2040  Germany2050
2040   France2030   France2040   France2050
2050  Belgium2030  Belgium2040  Belgium2050

